# Plotting a map with cartopy generates an error

Tags: python, cartopy

when I try to run the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import matplotlib.path as mpath
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.feature as cfeature
import shapely


ax=plt.axes(projection=ccrs.NorthPolarStereo())
ax.add_feature(cfeature.LAND,facecolor='green')

plt.show()
```

I get the following error:
`` python3: LineString.cpp:125: const geos::geom::CoordinateSequence* geos::geom::LineString::getCoordinatesRO() const: Assertion `nullptr != points.get()' failed. Aborted ``

I'm not sure the problem is coming from cartopy itself.
I'm running the code on Linux (Debian 10), python version is 3.7.3, shapely version 1.7.1, cartopy version is 0.18.0, libgeos version is 3.7.1

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, I had installed cartopy through pip, I reinstalled it by compiling it from the latest version from the git repository.